# Вставить текст в то место, где стоит курсор.

Tags: contenteditable, javascript

Пожалуй, последний вопрос, связанный с contenteditable.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tc5cF/

Как определить место, где стоит курсор и вставить туда что-нибудь по клику на кнопку?

Comment: @eicto, замечательно) Превратите свой комментарий в ответ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У execCommand же есть, insertText и insertHtml

Comment: @eicto, всё, спасибо :)